# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in

Tags: php, stream, steam

with setting up my automatic donation system for my site I have got everything working except on the last page I get this error. This is for a Garrys Mod server through Steam.

Error: Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamids=xxxxxxxxxxxxx) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /usr/www/angelgaming/public/multiple-rank/inc/page.verify.php on line

Verify.php code:

```
<?
    include('apikey.php');
    function toid($friendid) {
    if (substr($friendid,-1)%2==0) $server=0; else $server=1;
    $auth=bcsub($friendid,'76561197960265728');
    $auth=bcsub($auth,$server);
    $auth=bcdiv($auth,2);
    return "STEAM_0:".$server.':'.$auth;
    }
    $string = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $API_KEY . 'steamids=' . $_COOKIE['communityid']);
    $json_a = json_decode($string,true);
    $steamname = $json_a['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
    $avatar64 = $json_a['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull']; 

?>  
<h4>Verify the information below before you proceed</h4>
<div id="verify">
    <p><b><? echo $steamname; ?></b></p>
    <p><img id="avatar" src="<? echo $avatar64; ?>" style="border-radius: 8px;" /></p>
    <p><h6>Donation Amount: $<? echo RankPrice($_POST["rank"]) . CURRENCY;?></h6></p>
    <br />
    <p>
    <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/nz/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<? echo PAYPAL_EMAIL; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<? echo CURRENCY; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<? echo SERVER_NAME; ?> Donation (<? echo $steamname; ?>)">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<? echo toid($_COOKIE['communityid']) . '#' . $_POST["rank"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? echo RankPrice($_POST["rank"]); ?>">
    <input role="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Donate" type="submit" alt="Donate to Envidious via PayPal">
    <a href="" role="button" class="btn btn-danger">Go Back</a></form>
    </div>
```

Comment: 401 is from the far end server, saying you are not authorized, or authorization has failed.  So you need to check your auth credentials.

Comment: How do I check the auth credentials

Comment: your api key is more than likely your auth credential, you need to verify that you are using the correct one (I am assuming you XXXXX your key in the error message),

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the url listed in the docs https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29 
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=76561197960435530

It gives a 401 because its using an invalid key (XXXXXXXX) since you're getting a similar response it could also be that you're sending an invalid api key or no key at all?

Answer (score 1):

It may be user authentication detail issue. I have faced same issue and got below solution by passing user and password to header.

https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/using-authentication-and-filegetcontents

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by enabling auth mode in .htaccess, for example by the AuthType Basic directive